# Test blank cell and out put phonetic (text)

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code which first checks for blank cell in Column B, and then blank cells in Column F. If the results is Yes-No, then it prints the phonetic into F.

Can someone review the code, please? I am also wondering if there is a way to set the starting point to be Column B (therefore, Cells(i,1)=B1) and possibility replace Cells(i,2) by dim as something(long?).

```
Sub test()

'Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

'Set rng = Range("B:B")
i = 1

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2))

    If Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
        If Cells(i, 6).Value = "" Then
        Cells(i, 2).Offset(0, 4).Value = Cells(i, 2).Phonetic.Text
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: "I am also wondering if there is a way to set the starting point to be Column B (therefore, Cells(i,1)=B1) and possibility replace Cells(i,2) by dim as something(long?)?" 
Questions asking for [advice about code not yet written](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3651) are off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Give your code a good name** - not `test` - it doesn't tell me what it's doing.

At the same time, it's implicitly `public` so you might as well put that and always turn on `Option Explicit`. You can have it automatically by going to Tools -> Options in the VBE and checking the **Require Variable Declaration** option. This way if you have any variables not defined, the compiler will let you know.

You can use `Do Until isEmpty` but why not find the last cell and use a `For` loop? There is a [standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/1161309) way to find lastRow and lastColumn. That post explains why.

Technically you could eliminate `If Cells(i, 2) <> vbNullString` because the `lastRow` *should* determine that, but so would your `Do Until isEmpty` so it's *already* repetitive. You can also avoid assigning `i` an initial value and get rid of your messy (for VBA) iteration.

I would also eliminate the `if` block, personally.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetPhonetic()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 6) <> vbNullString Then Cells(i, 6) = Cells(i, 2).Phonetic.Text
    Next i
End Sub
```

Also eliminate the commented code - if you aren't using it, it's just noise. I also eliminated the extra white space as you don't need it.

---

Re:

> I am also wondering if there is a way to set the starting point to be
>   Column B (therefore, Cells(i,1)=B1) and possibility replace Cells(i,2)
>   by dim as something(long?)?

I'm not sure what you mean here, you are already `dim i as long` and using that to determine your starting point; there's no need for it to be more complicated than `cells(i,y)`.

Comment: Whoever suggested the anonymous edit for `value2` - please post a comment explaining your reasoning so we can all learn

Answer (score 0):

I think that [`SpecialCells()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) method would be very handy here to keep things very simple (no loops) and short (1 line)

```
Sub main()
    Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Offset(, 4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=PHONETIC(RC2)"
End Sub
```

where:

```
    Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
```

will filter column "B" non blank cells and reference them

```
    .Offset(, 4)
```

will shift referenced cells 4 columns to the left of referenced one

```
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
```

will filter these latter referenced cells blank ones

```
    .FormulaR1C1
```

will call the formula property of the referenced cells range to write in

```
    = "=PHONETIC(RC2)"
```

will write in referenced cells a formula that calls [PHONETIC()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837135.aspx) method that extracts the phonetic (furigana) characters from corresponding column "B" cells content, since RC2 stands for "current row column 2"

I must add that that *single-line* code assumes that there actually is at least one non blank cell in column "B" and at least one corresponding blank cell in column "F"

so that a minimal, but effective, handling of both assumptions failure could be

```
Sub main()
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Offset(, 4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=PHONETIC(RC2)"
End Sub
```